# How to intercept a Java Stream by a particular data?

Tags: java, file, stream, java-stream

I want to use Java to read a .txt file and use Java Stream to handle all the data before the Line "---".

I have used :

```
return Files.lines(Path.of(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .filter(n -> ...)
```

but I have no clue how to manage the lines or get access to other lines besides n(lambda parameter).

Comment: Why the insistence on using streams?  There are simpler approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> handle all the data before the Line "---"

To implement this condition you can use Java 9 [`Stream.takeWhile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)). It expects a `Predicate` as an argument. The stream processing would terminate after the first element for which the given predicate would be evaluated to `false`.

```
return Files.lines(Path.of(path))
    .takeWhile(line -> !"---".equals(line))
    // other logic
    // terminal operation producing the result, like .toList(), collect(Collectors.joining()), etc.
```

I suggest you to get familiar with these basic tutorials on [*Lambda expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [*Streams*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html).

***Sidenote:** `UTF_8` is the default character set, and there's no need to provide the second argument in `Files.lines()` if it's used in the target file.*

Comment: *UTF_8 is the default character set* Only >= Java 17 no?

Comment: @g00se No, since the time `Files.lines(path)` has been introduced into JDK, namely from Java 8. [See the Java 8'th Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-): *"works as if invoking it were equivalent to evaluating the expression: `Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`"*.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry - I was thinking of 'general `Reader`s' I think